# @property declaration without @synthesizing

Tags: ios, properties, synthesize

I am following Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming by Joe Conway and am kinda puzzled when I saw the following code.

WebViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

WebViewController.m

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@implementation WebViewController
- (void)loadView 
{
    // Create an instance of UIWebView as large as the screen
    // Tell web view to scale web content to fit within bounds of webview 
}

- (UIWebView *)webView
{
    return (UIWebView *)[self view];
}
@end
```

Shouldn't one synthesize the property declared in .h file? Xcode didn't give an warning either (which it usually does when I declare a property with synthesizing).

By the way, in the book, he also mentioned

> In WebViewController.h, add a property (but not an instance variable)

Doesn't declaring a property automatically generate an instance variable for you? Let me know what I missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the "`webView`" getter method is implemented in the .m file and because of that, "`@synthesize`" isn't necessary.

If a "`webView`" method wasn't explictly created in code, then the compiler would complain about the property not being synthesized.  Synthesizing a "read only" property, in this case, would only create a "getter" method which would do roughly the same thing you see in the code up there.

And yes, according to the [Apple docs on declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html), it says this about "`@synthesize`":

> You use the @synthesize directive to tell the compiler that it should synthesize the setter and/or getter methods for a property if
>   you do not supply them within the @implementation block. **The
>   @synthesize directive also synthesizes an appropriate instance
>   variable if it is not otherwise declared.**

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your help! Can't believe I missed the getter.

Comment: The latest version of XCode automatically synthesizes properties for you

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question, and one to which I think the answer is a bit subtle and often not immediate to people starting out with Objective-C. First of all let's dispel a myth about properties. The myth is this:

*Objective-C properties are related to instance variables*.

This is not necessarily true. It is *often* true, but not true in every case. Here's what is true:

*An Objective-C property declares a getter and a setter method*

(Or in the case of a `readonly` property, just a getter). In particular when you declare a property called `foo` (for the sake of discussion, let's assume it's not readonly), the only thing you are really doing is telling the compiler that the class you're writing has a method called `-foo` and a method called `-setFoo:`. By adding an `@synthesize foo;` declaration into the .m file, you are telling the compiler to generate those methods itself. Here you are saying, "Compiler, create an instance variable (also called `foo`) and generate implementations for my `-foo` and `setFoo:` methods that access this instance variable. In particular, return the value of this variable in `-foo` and set the value of the variable in `-setFoo:`.

Note, it is not necessary to have the compiler synthesize the methods for you. Rather, you can write `-foo` and `-setFoo:` yourself. Furthermore, you are not in any way required to create an instance variable to support the implementation of these methods. You can write them however you wish.

To summarize: the `@property` only tells the compiler about the existence of the getter and setter methods. You can then either: `@synthesize` the methods in your .m or write the methods yourself.

Comment: How come set/get properties still work without synthesizing?